# Pandas Dataframe grouping and standard deviation

Tags: python, pandas

Given a pandas dataframe in the following format:

```
GroupNo | at1 | at2 | at3   | at4 
1       | 0.02|1.12 | 1.88  | 3.2
1       | 6.11|1.13 | 0.88  | 5.2
4       | 2.02|1.16 | 2.88  | 0.2
3       | 0.20|0.12 | 1.48  | 1.25
2       | 0.02|1.12 | 1.88  | 1.4
3       | 3.02|1.12 | 1.98  | 2.2
3       | 0.40|0.18 | 1.48  | 1.25
```

How could I find the mean standard deviation per group?

For example, group by groupNo, find a standard deviation of the attributes in that group number, find a mean of them standard deviations

Any help would be great,
H

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you need [`GroupBy.std`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.std.html) with [`DataFrame.mean`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html):

```
print (df.groupby('GroupNo').std())
              at1       at2       at3       at4
GroupNo                                        
1        4.306280  0.007071  0.707107  1.414214
2             NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
3        1.573573  0.560833  0.288675  0.548483
4             NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN

print (df.groupby('GroupNo').std().mean(axis=1))
GroupNo
1    1.608668
2         NaN
3    0.742891
4         NaN
dtype: float64
```

Or maybe need:

```
print (df.groupby('GroupNo').mean().std(axis=1))
GroupNo
1    1.453848
2    0.788480
3    0.535371
4    1.149420
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thank you, will this include the group number in the std() calculation?

Comment: no, you can test it by `print (df.groupby('GroupNo')['at1','at2','at3','at4'].std())`

Comment: What is difference between groupby('GroupNo').std().mean(axis=1) and df.groupby('GroupNo').mean().std(axis=1) ? groupby.std.mean means standard deviation of mean values, and groupby.mean.st means the mean standard deviation of values ?